# Script in python-2.7 needs to call function from script written in python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function, version

Although I've provided background on my specific problem, this problem really has to to with calling functions coded in python3 within scripts written in python2. The background is just to help frame the issue.

I'm writing a script plugin for ArcGIS 10 (mapping software), which can only use python version 2.7. But in the script, i want to feed an image into a neural net programmed in tensorflow 2.0, which requires python 3.x.

I have a working script for ArcGIS that gets the map image as a numpy array (python 2.7).

I have a working script in python 3.6 that takes a numpy array image, feeds it into the network and outputs the predictions.

Process overview:

1. ArcGIS creates thousands of map images (complicated math and process)
2. Feed each image into a tensorflow neural network and record predictions
3. ArcGIS takes all collected predictions as a single array and does further analysis and mapping.

Right now I have a 3-step process that involves leaving ArcGIS.

1. Run ArcGIS plugin script - save list of files, one for each img (tens of thousands of files).
2. Separate script in python 3.6 (executed in an IDE) to iterate through the files, and read each prediction, save it into another numpy array. save array to disk
3. Run another ArcGIS plugin script to read that outputted numpy array file and send it back to ArcGIS, ArcGIS analyses predictions.

Desired workflow:

Arcgis plugin creates each image, and directly feeds it into my tensorflow model, and writes the predictions to a nparray. at end of this same script, the plugin can analyze the resulting nparray. So basically cutting out all the writes to the file system since that is just a workaround for the different python versions.

[Also, ideally, the files are only needed temporarily in RAM but end up taking 6 GB of disk space in total since I need to switch scripts]

Problem:
I can't figure out how to get the numpy array to be passed back and forth between the python2 script and the python3 script. when I try to import tensorflow in the python2 script it's not found, when I try to import the ArcGIS python api into python3, it says not found.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: wow, maybe complain to esri about how old their version of Python is!  more constructively, how about using the `subprocess` module in Python 2.7 to run Python 3.6 on your code?

Comment: I've been trying to play with that but the examples only show how to return whether the process ran successfully. How do I get a numpy array result from the process? Never used subprocess before.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I got subprocesses working. But ended up dumping all the data into a huge h5 file and using that as the bridge between python environments. Then used 4 different scrips to go through the steps. The h5 file ended up being waaaay faster than mini files. And was cleaner code than subprocesses